# "Uncomfortable" in the physical sense

Tags: words, word-requests

I'm trying to say:

> My brother does not use headphones and earpieces **because he finds them uncomfortable.**

And the basic sentence structure I have in mind is:

> 兄は **(reason)** からヘッドフォンやイヤフォンを使わない。

But I'm not sure how to phrase the "finds them uncomfortable" part as I'm not sure what word/phrase can express this correctly. I found words like 気｛き｝詰｛づ｝まり, 気｛き｝味｛み｝悪｛わる｝い etc in the dictionary but they all seem to deal with the emotional aspect of comfort, such as feeling safe, calm etc. I'm looking for words that refer to physical discomfort, in this context, because headphones are too heavy, stuffy, bulky etc.

Can those words be also used for describing this physical discomfort, or are there better words to express this situation?

Answer (score 3):

The best expression I could think of for that situation would be:

> 「着{つ}け心地{ごこち}が悪{わる}い」

I could not think of a better one for describing discomfort with headphones, earpieces, etc.

Neither 「気詰まり」 nor 「気味悪い」 would work here **at all**.  They do not even come close.

You could also use:

> 「着けていて心地よくない」.